# How to select multiple rows in JTable?

Tags: java, swing

How can I handle multiple rows selection in a `JTable`? here is the code I have been using for selecting only one row:

```
table1 = new JTable();
        table1.setModel(Ajmodel);
        table1.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {
                selectedAJ_ID = (Integer) table1.getModel().getValueAt(table1.getSelectedRow(), 0);
            }
        });
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can allow multiple selection by 
`jTable.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
jTable.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);`

and you can get the values by

```
if (jTable.getSelectedRows() > -1) {

                 int[] selectedrows = jTable.getSelectedRows();

                 for (int i = 0; i < selectedrows.length; i++)
                {

                     System.out.println(jTable.getValueAt(selectedrows[i], 0).toString());

                }

            }
```

Comment: If I set this property, how would I handle the listener?

Comment: `int[]i=new int[table1.getSelectedRowCount()];
    for(int j=table1.getSelectedRow();j<table1.getSelectedRow()+table1.getSelectedRowCount();j++){
     i[j]=(int) table1.getValueAt(j, 0);
    }` try this to get the ID's you selected

Comment: you can try `int[] selectedrows = jTable.getSelectedRows();` to get selected rows

Comment: @UX that returns the index of the rows you selected but not the values

Comment: @XtremeBaumer @TiMr From the selected indexes values can be get by `jTable.getModel().getValueAt(row_index, col_index);`

Comment: `int[]i=new int[table1.getSelectedRowCount()];
    for(int j=0;j<table1.getSelectedRowCount();j++){
     i[j]=(int) table1.getValueAt(table1.getSelectedRow()+j, 0);
    }` probably a workaround. no need for 2 arrays here

Comment: @XtremeBaumer nice tries, but I gess the idea is to parse `table1.getSelectedRows()` as `s int[]` with the implementation of `getValueAt(s[i],0)`, I am testing it now, please consider providing an answer.

Comment: @TiMr if you add a button and add `JButton showDialogButton = new JButton("Text Button");
showDialogButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  { make the readings
    }
});`

Comment: @UX, Thanks, it works.

Comment: I am glad :) @TiMr